# AngularJS controller not found when copying code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making the *Try AngularJS: Beginner's Guide* on udemy and I'm having a strange issue. The following code works for the course manager, but not for some users.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app='try'>
    <head>
        <script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="./js/app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/app/app.config.js"></script>

        <script src="./js/app/blog-list/blog-list.module.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/app/blog-list/blog-list.component.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='' ng-controller='BlogListController'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('try', ['blogList']);
```

**app.config.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('try', [])
    .config(function(){});
```

**blog-list.module.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('blogList', []);
```

**blog-list.component.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('blogList').
    controller('BlogListController', function(){
        console.log("hello")
    });
```

I get an error

> The controller with the name 'BlogListController' is not registered.

But if in the file **blog-list.component.js** I change the module name:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('try').           <---- CHANGED THIS
    controller('BlogListController', function(){
        console.log("hello")
    });
```

It works.

Why does the code before the fix work for the course manager? Which is the real correct answer?

PS: Everything is loaded on the order that the `index.html` files states.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because the controller does not exist inside `try` module. which you have declared in the html `ng-app='try'`. add `ng-pp="blogList"` in html then will work

Comment: @SibiRaj So why does the code of the instructor work with `ng-app="try"`?

Comment: I don't know what the instructor said. a simple logic. you have defined that in another module. how can you expect that to work somewhere, where the controller is never defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try` module is loaded without a dependency on the `blogList` module, because `app.config.js` contains a very subtle error.

Note that the `angular.module` function can be used in two ways: to retrieve a module and to create a new module. A new module is created when a second argument is provided. This second argument contains the dependencies of the module.

That means that the module is loaded in this application as follows: First, `angular.module('try', ['blogList'])` creates a new module, named `try`, with a dependency on `blogList`. Then `angular.module('try', []).config(function(){})` creates a new module named `try` without any dependencies, overriding the  previous `try`.

Simply remove the second argument so **app.config.js** looks like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('try')
    .config(function(){});
```

and it should always work.